# Dynamically resize/move a layer based on the variable size/position of a separate text layer

Tags: javascript, variables, dataset, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a psd with a text element, displayed as a title, followed by a smaller text which acts a sort of class description:

[image: The text]

This could be for example: Arthur (King, Human).
I have a .csv file in which these titles and classes are listed.
I now want to replace these texts, but the following is the problem:

**Using only 1 text element:** The whole text will get replaced and the styling of the smaller part (the classes) is lost.

**Using 2 text elements:** The class text will be overlapped if the title is longer and won't neatly move with the title part.

What I desire is that this happens:

[image: desired result]

I tried searching the web for alignment options or if the layers could be linked somehow, I just can't seem to find the answer to that. The best would either be

- If the "classes layer" would always align to the right border of the "title layer", or
- If the variables I import would have an option to add styling (Something like: `"Arthur <font style='Regular' size='6'>(King, Human)</font>"`.

I just can't seem to find anything on how to do that. It would be fine by me if scripting is an answer here, but in that case I just don't know where to begin.

*Photoshop 2023 is being used

Comment: Scripting this is your best solution, using two separate text layers (one for the title, a second for the class). Script would simply set the text for both layers, then update the position of the class layer based on the title layer (`title.position.x + title.width + padding`), optionally adjusting position of both once the total width is determined to fixup alignment.

Comment: How did you update the text such that the style was lost?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the `insertCaption` method from `ContactSheetII.jsx` (line 8664). This script comes bundled with your Photoshop installation, and is located at `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2023\Presets\Scripts\ContactSheetII.jsx`. Adding custom text layer, positioning, and measuring their sizes are all demonstrated in that method, and a minimal but fully functional script implementing layer exporting in a loop is linked below.

If you're new to scripting Photoshop, browse through some of the other smaller scripts in the same directory also to get a feel for how they manipulate document layers.

My approach would be to parse through your dataset, running a loop for each entry that:

- Duplicates two pre-styled base layers (`titleLayer` & `classLayer`)
- Updates the text for both
- Checks `titleLayer.width + classLayer.width + padding` to ensure they fit inside the horizontal bounds of the document

  - If boundary fails, decrease font size of both slightly and recheck, looping this step until they fit
- Optionally adjust `titleLayer.position` (maybe unnecessary, if left-aligned is suitable)
- Update `classLayer.position` on the X axis to be same as `titleLayer.position.x + titleLayer.width + padding`
- Handle any final processing ([grouping the two layers, saving to file, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73638769/9412456))
- Cleanup, rinse, repeat